# What does a "psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1" message mean?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, dmesg

This is the output of `dmesg|tail`

```
[13064.329754] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynched.
[13067.095373] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[13067.104046] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[13067.113075] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynched.
[13073.819724] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[13073.820864] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[13073.822467] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[13073.824034] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[13073.825164] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[13073.825172] psmouse.c: issuing reconnect request
```

What does this mean?  I have Ubuntu 11.04, HP  Pavillion DV6-1149WM.

My touchpad seems to be working fine.  My keyboard however, sometimes screws up, for example, instead of typing "word", it will type "wwww", it 'freezes up' and after a little bit, that's when it types the duplicate keys instead of all the different keys I typed.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)